# Detailed find/replace using script/macro

Tags: sql, powershell, notepad++

I have been looking around for something that will allow me to make many changes across many files as part of a database migration where object names with similar business meaning have changed names.  The idea would be to iterate through all *.sql files, for example, and provide a list of old string and new string values to replace.  A UI like Notepad++ has macros, and they're nice, but hard to manage at a large scale with so many files and so many replacement values.

Let's take this for instance.

`select last_name from members`

last_name is now surname, and members is now people.  So

`select surname from people`

Pretty easy, but there are some more complicated ones.  It might be nice to not break any existing code by aliasing fields.

`select surname as last_name from people as members`

Nothing downstream breaks, but what if it's already aliased like `last_name as last_name`.  What if there's another field called `person_last_name` which also matches the "last_name" pattern?  I'll take whatever I can get, and I don't expect to not have to review code (that would be a TERRIBLE idea anyway, maybe add comments to note that something was changed via macro/script) but a good base to start.

Is something like this possible in a relatively easy way?  Keep in mind that I'll probably have 100+ object names to change.

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using? Your best bet is to find a library that can parse the appropriate syntax/dialect, thus allowing you to very specifically change names only of columns for example, handle columns that are already aliased, etc.

Comment: Source is Hadoop/Impala, destination is TSQL/SQL Server/Azure Synapse

Comment: I mean the sql scripts you're hoping to update - are they T-SQL, HQL or Impala SQL? Or a mix?

Comment: Source scripts are Impala

Comment: Please, show us a sample file with several test cases and expected result